Dymola not working properly. Opening takes 10 Minutes. Dymosim.exe always simulating
I am currently writing my master thesis and I run into an issue which I am not able to resolve myself. First of all it would be great to avoid a new installation, because I need to go to university to borrow a new license.
So I made a simulation of my system and I am doing a parameter study, so the modell was simulated approx. 30 times before with different values for the rotational speed. So I know it works.
I made a simulation with a pretty high value and the simulation crashed. Dymola closed it self and when I tried to open it again, it did not open. After 15 minutes it plopped up again. Normaly a simulation of the systems takes 50s. Now it instanly show "no response" from the dymola window after pressing the simulate button.
enter image description here
What did I try:

I opened dymosim.exe and stopped the process manually by holding crtl + C. The window closes then by itself after some time. When I open it again, the same issue appears. It is trying to simulate something.

I tried to delete every single file which contains temporary data.

I deleted dymosim.exe and pulled the inital one which I used from the beginning. Same issue, something seems to trigger the simulation process.

I also had an error message which contained "package.order" is not complete. CodingConventions are missing, but I cant find anything related to this via google, stackoverflow or so on.


Last resort would be deinstalling the programm and downloading it newly and getting a new license key. Would be the last step... Hope to avoid that one.
Any help is highly appreciated.

So I just downloaded the Demo Version of Dymola 2024x and there everything is working as aspected.
The version I was using before was Dymola 2023. Still realy confused, that it started acting so weird from kind of out of nowhere.

Have you tried checking C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\DassaultSystemes\Dymola\[DYMOLAVERSION]\setup.dymx? There should be separate files for 2023 and 2024x. First check would be renaming the one for 2023x...

To me it sounds that something has overwritten your Dymola 2023 installation, or that the operating system has crashed. But if Dymola 2024x works for you I would use that instead. Or even 2024x Refresh 1. Newer is better.

It is worth noting that Dymola license keys are usually upward compatible. So installing a new Dymola version shouldn't be an issue.

So thanks to all who are trying to support.
I installed the 2024 version and it worked for a few simulations but after 3-5 sims it started crashing again and freezing after every sim. I then decided to make the step to fully recover the pc and install 2024x refresh 1 and picked a new license at the university. (Borrowed via license server).
The only difference I now recognize is that I now need to be connected to my vpn of my university, that dymola can load the license key. With the 2023 Version that was not necessary.
I can no solve the problem, but I can say it now works again properly, after setting up the computer newly.
